# Cocoa iOS Parsing JSON Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa

I am new at coding for iOS currrently trying to rework some aJax code so that a JSON array resultset can be properly parsed by the below code.

## JSON Return String

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Original Tutorial

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-ios/

## iOS Code

```
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization     JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];
         //self.greetingId.text = [[greeting objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue];
         //self.greetingContent.text = [greeting objectForKey:@"content"];

         self.greetingId.text = [[greeting objectForKey:@"employees"] stringValue];
         self.greetingContent.text = [greeting objectForKey:@"firstName"];
     }
 }];
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Although it is not clear from the question what the actual problem is, here are some issues spotted in this snippet: 1) `objectForKey:@"employees"` will return an `NSArray` so I guess `stringValue` is not really what you're looking for 2) `objectForKey:@"firstName"` of `greeting` dictionary (remember, this is your root object) would return `nil`. I hope that this makes sense & steer you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Your "employees" is an array that has multiple firstname and lastname dictionaries init, so what you are trying in your code is wrong.

You need to create an array from with employees objectkey. that will give you multiple dictionaries , and to access those dictionaries you can use a for loop and assign the keys to strings.

```
NSArray *employeesArray = [greeting objectForKey:@"employees"];  

for (NSDictionray *dict in employeesArray) {
   NSString *firstname = [[dict objectForKey:@"firstName"] stringValue];
   NSString *lastName = [[dict objectForKey:@"lastName"] stringValue];
   // do something with names
}
```

Comment: I added an explanation

Comment: like the following pastebin not even sure how to do something with the text... want to print out the names... -> http://pastebin.com/yv92v0RT

Comment: yes, but you are not doing anything with the names in that code, you are more than one first and last name in that json example you posted in your question and your question is not complete. what are you trying to achive, what errors you are getting etc...

Comment: I want to use the example I posted and parse through a json array, but perhaps I need a more simple tutorial, first piece of objective-c code I am missing with, used to coding in PHP, JSON, etc... You know of a simpler tutorial than the one I posted?

Comment: That seems simple enough, but I assume the json strings are different, like a said your json has an employees array with multiple dictionaries in it, for that my code should work.

Comment: made the following changes to code, it builds successfully, but debugger throws out error -> revised code and error http://pastebin.com/wSqsNfJE